# Why there are two different Javascripts?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript, but the tutorial are kind of different depending on the resources. It looks like the JavaScipts are different, there is like 2 types of it.

So, let's say if we take one source, they have a code like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Before the script...</p>
        <script>
            alert( 'Hello, world!' );
        </script>
        <p>...After the script.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I do tutorial, on Codecademy , for example, they do not have any html code, no body, p, script... the code does not go into html. Functions like alert, onclick are very popular and, in fact, the w3schools begins with these functions, where on Codecademy there are no such things. And this code line

`document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date();`

it says it is important in javascript, but codecademy does not mention it at all! Like what are those document dot getElementById('demo').What is it doing? Why it is everywhere on w3schools, but not on Codecademy, if it is so important? I finished whole JavaScript course on Codecademy, but I am still confused how come it is so different?
I learned Python before and it is similar to proper JavaScript (I call proper JavaScript the one, that is on Codecademy, because the structure is just like Python)
So the weird JavaScript (the one that is on w3schools, etc. and not on Codecademy) often has dollar sign, lines like this

`function $(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}`

The proper JavaScript use dollar signs only with string interpolations and that's it and the whole Codecademy tutorial does not have this all weird code that I provided above, which seems really important on other web sources.
All the YouTube tutorials I found are also using proper JavaScript, just declaring variables, writing functions, like, normal programming language, like Python, but what's with  all the HTML tags, alerts, onclicks, dollar signs, etc., that are in tutorials like w3schools? Can please someone explain me?

Yes, I'm embarrassed a lot. To think of that I know Python and JavaScript on higher than beginner level, but I cannot figure out what's with the different code and what is happening...

P.S. Thank you everyone for answers. I probably wasn't clear, but I didn't wanted you to explain what actually those code lines, that I posted, meant (like most of you did), but mainly I wanted to know how come it's so different, why is that difference, why two different types of JavaScript? Hence, I accepted the appropriate answer.

Comment: The $ sign should be seen as any other letter there. Eg `function r(x)` is equivalent to `function $(x)` -- you call the first function like `r()` and the second by `$()`

Comment: These websites probably have a different syllabus. Javascript is a rich scripting language and even comprehensive online courses don't cover everything at once. It is also possible one website may teach a more recent version of Javascript(Also known as ECMAScript) which may cause some functions to look bizzare. I suggest you find a good book or course teaching the most recent version. Then go ahead and practice by making projects and collabarating on open source projects. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one on Codecademy mostly deals with server-sided Javascript, read up on NodeJS if you want to know more about it.
The other one with document.getElementById() and such is client-side Javascript and it gets executed by you or anyone who visits the webpage (so the client) inside of the browser.

NodeJS on the other hand doesn't run in a browser and doesn't have a global document or window because of that. You can use it to make a webserver (check out Express) or use it for other stuff in the same way you would use other languages like for example Python.

Both of them are still the same Javascript but they run in a different context.
The dollar sign is pretty typical jQuery syntax, it's just a framework for Javascript where they decided to use $ as variable name (which is allowed) so you could easily see it's a function from jQuery. There's nothing preventing you from using $ yourself in variable names, not in NodeJS and not in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById` is part of the DOM API, it's not part of JavaScript. If you want to interact with webpages you need html that is parsed and "converted" into DOM tree like structure. For example `document` don't exist in Node.js (server side JavaScript) but there is library that allow to use if you want to test your front-end code.

`<script>` tag is a way to add JavaScript files to html page. But you don't need html page to use JavaScript (you can use Node.js that I've mentioned).

and about this:

```
function $(x) {return document.getElementById(x);}
```

`$` is normal variable and function name, it's legacy for Prototype and jQuery libraries that used this for their API main entry point and it's very short and clean.

Answer (score 0):

There are arguably more than 2 even!

Javascript was developed to work inside the browser, in the context of the DOM, but it is also a programming language independent of any browser, of any HTML, of any DOM.

In HTML, `<script>` tags are for javascript, but you can also link to javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

the `<script>` tag is just a html element which declares the content of this block to be javascript. 
the content will be executed by the browser inside of the scope of the DOM.

in a javascript application you do not code javascript directly into the DOM, instead the JS files will be included/injected into the page.

Answer (score 0):

When you see `getElement` usually its trying to find an element from DOM tree, in your case it's trying to find and element with the id `demo`.

Would find something like this

```html
<div class="container">
     <p id="demo"> </p>
</div>
```

For the code `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = new Date()` this would get the date and set it to your HTML #demo node.

As for `function $(x) {return document.getElementById(x);}` this function is trying to copy jQuery funtion of selecting DOM. Its does the same thing as the above code but you type alot less once its declared.

```
function $(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

$('demo') // finds all nodes that have #demo in your DOM tree
```

In your HTML snippet using `<script>` before and after a tag means that you have or not to wait for the document to load. DOM tree loads from one node to the next and when you load a JS file or script, it gets instant loaded and fired, unless its told no to using events and conditions.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Before the script...</p> 

        <!-- This element exists in your DOM tree already so you 
        don't really need the document to load. -->

        <script>
            alert( 'Hello, world!' );
        </script>

        <p>...After the script.</p> 

        <!-- This element is added after the script so if you run 
        the code above trying to find this "p" tag you would need 
        to add a proper window.onload event -->

    </body>
</html>
```